# Return words based on index in Spacy

Tags: python, spacy

I want to use the dependency parser of spaCy to define the scope of negation within my doc.

[image]

I have the following code:

```
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
doc = nlp(u'Hi alll, some dividend is omnipresent even if not paid')

negation_tokens = [tok for tok in doc if tok.dep_ == 'neg']
negation_head_tokens = [token.head for token in negation_tokens]
print(negation_tokens)      # not
print(negation_head_tokens) # paid

for token in negation_head_tokens:
    # print(token.text, token.dep_, token.head.text, token.head.pos_, [child for child in token.children])
   start = token.i         # 5
   end = token.head.i      # 10
   negated_tokens = doc(start, end)  # this an gives error
```

The desired output should be:

```
 is omnipresent even if not paid
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the `doc` is a string, it can't be called (like a method). What you want is to index it (get a small part). Use square brackets for this instead:

```
negated_tokens = doc[start:end]
```

Although actually what you want is

```
negated_tokens = doc[end:start + 1]
print(negated_tokens)
> is omnipresent even if not paid
```